# Bootstrap divs jumping out of parent div on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I got a problem with some bootstrap divs that wont stay in their parent div on mobile. It's probably just a float issue, but i really can't figure it out!

The problem looks like this:

[image: The problem]

[And the link for the site is here.](http://xn--fnpark-pua9l.dk/materialer/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the parent div with class `content-container` an additional class `clearfix`.

Bootstrap has this set up as a helper class to help with issues such as this. Which is caused by floated child elements not giving their parent height.

There are many places on the internet you can read up on why you need to clear floats. For example you can [read here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) from CSS Tricks. Specifically for your case look under the heading 'The Great Collapse'

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks! your answer was very useful to me! it solved to me the same problem of bjarkof! :-)